# BMW jumping to park at stop

Tags: automatic-transmission, bmw, x1

My BMW X1 (2013, 2.0L Turbo) occasionally jumps to Park when I'm stopped at a light. It happens whether the auto engine start/stop function is on or off. I then have to put the car in drive again to proceed, but no issues doing this. Has anyone else experienced this? Any solutions?

Comment: Does it have paddle shifters?